# How to extract substring based on position of a character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a String as following Jack_XX3_20 , I need to retrieve 20 based on position of XX3. I am using following code but it returns k_XX3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Test The Code</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Jack_XX3_20YYYG";
    var pos = str.indexOf("XX3");
    var n = str.substring(pos+3,3);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
</script>
```

Comment: I am not good in taking guess what is the down vote for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ?

`str.substring(str.indexOf("XX3")+4, str.length)`

This is how you want to use substring

> str.substring(indexA[, indexB])

**indexA**

```
An integer between 0 and the length of the string, specifying the offset into the string of the first character to include in the returned substring.
```

**indexB**

```
Optional. An integer between 0 and the length of the string, which specifies the offset into the string of the first character not to include in the returned substring.
```

Source: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

**UPDATE**

You are looking for a regex based on the comment

```js
var str = "Jack_XX3_24930YYYG";
var reg = /XX3_(\+?\d+)/g;
var match = reg.exec(str);
alert(match[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem of the code is if anything exist after 20 it catch that as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should work(Tested in JSFiddle):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Jack_XX3_20";
    var pos = str.indexOf("XX3_")+4;
    var n = str.substring(pos,str.length);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function myFunction() {
   var str = "Jack_XX3_20qjjjj";
    var pos = str.lastIndexOf("XX3_")+3;

    var pos = str.indexOf("XX3_")+4;
    var n = str.substring(pos,pos+2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jh2sd7zt/1/)**